# Sitecore Lucene search indexing and subfolders

Tags: search, lucene, sitecore, root

**How can I make Lucene include results, indexed outside the siteroot eg. stuff based with a root of fx.** "/sitecore/content/stuff", but not placed in "/sitecore/content/Home".

Taking a look at SearchManager.cs in "/sitecore modules/LuceneSearch/, the SiteRoot is defined as "SiteCore.Content.Site.Startpath", but making any changes to this file dosent seem to have any affect.

Note:
I am only using the "LuceneResults".ascx & .cs.

----- Question updated, as I narrowed in what the problem might be -----

Im trying to create an index of a specific set of items, for use in a Lucene search.
In web.config, I have specified an index containing:

```
 ...
 <root>/sitecore/content/Home/Subfolder</root>
 ...
```

and that works flawlessly, getting all the subitems when doen a search.

I have then copied exactly the same items to a new location, and updated my web.config as following:

```
 ...
 <root>/sitecore/content/newSubfolder/Subfolder/Subfolder</root>
 ...
```

Now my searches never finds anything!
Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem here.

Note:
- I have rebuild the Search Index db, at every change.
- In "Luke" the index seems fine, and the the search here yields the proper results.

Complete Index:

```
<index id="faqindex" type="Sitecore.Search.Index, Sitecore.Kernel">
    <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
    <param desc="folder">__faq</param>
    <Analyzer ref="search/analyzer"/>
    <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
        <resources type="Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler, Sitecore.Kernel">
            <database>master</database>
                      <root>/sitecore/content/MyContent/Snippets/FAQ</root>
            <include hint="list:IncludeTemplate">
                <faqblock>{3340AAAE-B2F8-4E22-8B7B-F3EDDB48587E}</faqblock>
            </include>
            <tags>faqblock</tags>
            <boost>1.0</boost>
        </resources>
    </locations>
</index>
```

Comment: If the index is filled with the correct items after re-indexing, you should look at the code that is used to retrieve the search-results.

Comment: I would think the same, but nothing have been changed except the "root" tag in the index, even without going into how the results are displayed, the return results.Count == 0.

Comment: Try rebuilding the index. It may not solve the problem but worth a try.

Comment: Ive rebuild the index at every change. Question updated, as ive narrowed down what seems to be problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are using the **[Lucene Search](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Lucene_Search.aspx)** module from Sitecore Marketplace.  The code for this module limits the search results to the site root and its children:

```
 public SearchManager(string indexName)
 {
   SearchIndexName = indexName;
   Database database = Factory.GetDatabase("master");
   var item = Sitecore.Context.Site.StartPath;
   SiteRoot = database.GetItem(item);
}
[...]
public SearchResultCollection Search(string searchString)
{
  //Getting index from the web.config
  var searchIndex = Sitecore.Search.SearchManager.GetIndex(SearchIndexName);
  using(IndexSearchContext context = searchIndex.CreateSearchContext())
  {
     SearchHits hits = context.Search(searchString, new SearchContext(SiteRoot));
```

*sitecore modules\Lucene Search\SearchManager.cs*

Assuming that the "website" node in the **sites** section of Web.config has startItem="/home", results outside of the "home" hierarchy will not be returned.

If you download the source code for this project, and edit the line that populates SiteRoot to the following, the new items will be returned:

```
SiteRoote = database.GetItem("/sitecore/content");
```

Remember to copy the new LuceneSearch.dll to the bin directory of the website project.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and this was more or less what I also come to at the end, though you cleared up a couple of things. Answer accepted.